# Are multiple cURL multi handles allowed in single event loop?

Tags: multithreading, curl, libcurl

I am creating a server which will handle multiple concurrent clients connections (approx 100), where the clients pumps in lots of data and server packages and sends it off to another remote location.

What I would like to do is to 'group' the data sent from each client into their own data structures (say some linked list) and have these lists processed concurrently.  Throughput is important so I would like to be able to send as much data concurrently as possible (lets say up to 10k easy handles processed concurrently).

The approaches I am thinking of are:

1. Have a large thread pool (say 100 threads) where each process an easy handle.
2. Have a single thread handling a multi-handle for all 10k easy handles.
3. Create several threads (say 4) handling a multi-handle, so each handles 2500 easy handles.
4. Have a multi-handle per client, so potentially 100 threads each processing a multi-handle.

What I'd like to know is whether I can 'combine' #2 and #3 such that I have a single thread which handles multiple multi-handles in a single event loop.  Is such a thing allowed, and if so, would it even make sense?  If it is possible, it would satisfy my requirement of grouping client processing per multi-handle, and also would allow me to take advantage of persistent connections per multi-handle.  If not, the only way for me to fully take advantage of persistent connections for all clients would be option #4.  Preferably I'd like to reduce the number of threads used due to certain constraints with the programming model we're following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is such a complicated question it isn't possible to answer briefly. It will also depend on a lot of local conditions and other requirements you may have but isn't specified here. I would suggest you build a few prototypes and measure them against each other for your particular conditions.

**Yes**: you can use multiple multi-handles in the same thread but it would probably get a bit quirky and I don't think you'd see any benefits from that rather than just using one and adding all easy-handles to that single one.

My personal preference would be #3, but perhaps go with slightly more threads than 4 simply because today you easily have CPUs with 8 threads and soon there will be 16 and for the cases you're CPU-bound you're better to spread out the load as much as possible for highest performance (but not too much to still gain from caches and connection re-use etc).

Also, since each multi-handle then handles N easy-handles there's always the risk that you have to do something for a special transfer that makes the other N-1 transfers pause for a little bit, and then it is better if you've split up the total over several threads so that it doesn't block all transfers then.

Finally, to get this speedy you might want to use the [curl_multi_socket_action](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html) event-based API for maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response! If going with option #3, I was planning on having as many threads a cores, so totally agree with you. My plan was also to use the `curl_multi_socket_action` API, so it seems I was on the right track (this is my first time using curl). It's still good to know it is allowed to have multiple multi-handes per thread, but I think I'll be going with option #3 and see how this goes.